# How can i use metamask in my mobile app ( flutter / dart )

Tags: api, flutter, dart, mobile-application, metamask

I want to create a mobile app with metamask but when i search for this idea i just found only web project. So how can i use metamask Wallet info in my mobile app. Anyone work on like this project? I need an roadmap and suggestion.